# is there a way to determing if a sidekiq job has not completed or manage transitions through stages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I'd like to be able to have a callback if a sidekiq job has not `completed` in 10 seconds (probably send an SMS or somethign via Twilio). When a sidekiq job is not running, it is critical for my business - I honestly like to see and track every change through the different statuses of a job and log it. Say for example, any job is taking over 20 seconds, then I should be alerted.

I'd like this logic to be part of my Worker `perform` method as I don't want to manage in my Rails conttroller.

I've seen sidekiq-status https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status from this SO question [Best way to monitor for completion of a Sidekiq job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370574/best-way-to-monitor-for-completion-of-a-sidekiq-job). But it's not clear to me how this should be working. Should I be polling for the status? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to monitor queue latency. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#monitoring-queue-latency

Comment: thx for response, kinda  a couple of issues in my original question. thinking through this, I think I'm going to create a skq_current object / table which will be a list of currently executing sidekiq jobs and when they finish move to a skq_log table which will keep a record of the length of time of each job. I'll also create a clockwork job that will check the skq_current table every 10 seconds and increment a count and send a text SMS if anything is taking > 30 seconds. A bit excessive maybe but critical that these jobs are monitored VERY closely. thx again and if any thoughts, lmk